# SEVERE: Error filterStart ++++ SEVERE: Exception starting filter SessionFilter

Tags: java, tomcat

When im trying to build my dynamic web project the following logs are coming up and im not sure how to resolve this issue..any help??

catalina.2013-09-26.logs

```
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Sep 26, 2013 4:32:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext s.2013tart
SEVERE: Context [/iaf] startup failed due to previous errors
```

localhost.2013-09-26.logs

```
Sep 26, 2013 4:32:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart


SEVERE: Exception starting filter SessionFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sevices.authentication.SessionFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4363)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:830)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1217)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1337)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: A short guess, "sevices.authentication.SessionFilter" should be "services.authentication.SessionFilter"

Comment: no its rightly written

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First port of call : I'd say your web.xml has declared a filter, and you've got the wrong class name in the definition

Comment: @user2793926 if it didn't solved your problem why you marked this as answer?

Comment: If this is not your answer then don't have to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In your web application, there is a missing class `sevices.authentication.SessionFilter`.

This means that either:

1. The class containing `sevices.authentication.SessionFilter` is not found in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory, OR
2. Your class `sevices.authentication.SessionFilter`, in your web application, didn't compile into `WEB-INF/classes` folder.

Make sure your code compiles with no errors and deploys correctly (WAR file).